# How to track email using ses api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When i sent email, I needed to **track opens, clicks detail** for my emails, so that i can identify those users who read the email. I am using amazon ses api.

Is it possible to track email using **ses api**?

any Idea?

Comment: Yes it is. This post details how: https://mailintel.io/resources/tracking-deliveries-opens-and-clicks-for-amazon-ses

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) can be used to send emails with improved delivery rates.

However, it only sends the content (text, HTML) that you directly provide. **It does not modify your message in any way**. Therefore, it does **not** track opens, clicks and reads.

To track such activity, you would need to insert tracking codes in the email messages that you provide to Amazon SES. This is commonly done via email marketing software such as [Marketo](https://www.marketo.com/) and [the SalesForce marketing cloud](https://www.marketingcloud.com/).

**UPDATE:** In August 2017, **open and click tracking** was added to Amazon SES.

See: [Open and Click Tracking Have Arrived | AWS Messaging & Targeting Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/)

Comment: Can we generate these tracking links?

Comment: @AkashShindhe Click tracking has since been added. See above link.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Amazon SES event destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/event-destinations-manage.html) as a solution for this task. It supports open-and-click events